# How does one configure KeepAlive on Grpc.AspNetCore.Client?

Tags: grpc, grpc-dotnet

I'm trying to configure the [KeepAlive](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/keepalive.md) settings for a gRPC connection using [Grpc.Net.Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/client?view=aspnetcore-3.1). The [original SDK](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15423) supports this through injecting `ChannelOption` objects into the `Channel` constructor. What I can't see is any way to set this up through the new .NET Core 3.1 API. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the Grpc.Net.Client does not currently provide configurable keepalive support (it requires feature support from the underlying HttpClient)
This might be available in the future, see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/41852 for details.